# Birt use values from dataset at initialize phase

Tags: birt

I am using XML as the data source in my birt report.
I would like to know if there is a way to use values from dataset at the initializing phase.

Answer (score 0):

No. But why would you want to do this?

The initialize event is meant to define JS functions and variables that you want to use at different places in the report.

Comment: I want to write a function which enters values into the report

Comment: If the values come from outside of the report, you have to use report parameters. The one and only use-case which is similar to what you describe is if you want to use a data set as a list-of-values for a report parameter.